# Colorings versus geometric group theory method

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, chessboard

Consider the following famous problem:

> Two opposite corner cells of a chessboard are removed. Prove that it is impossible to cover remaining cells with dominoes $2\times1$.

The standard proof uses coloring: the removed cells are of the same color and any domino covers 1 black and 1 white cell.

However, there is another proof via geometric group theory: for each cell write $a, b, a^{-1}, b^{-1}$ on its left, upper, right, lower border correspondingly.  Suppose that chessboard without two opposite corners can be covered by dominoes. That would mean that any two elements $a, b$ of any group satisfying $a^2 b a^{-2} b^{-1}=1$  and $ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2} = 1$ will also satisfy $a^7 b a b^7 a^{-7} b^{-1} a^{-1} b^{-7}=1$. The idea here is that we go clockwise along the border of some subset of cells and intepret the written word as a relation.

[image]

When two regions have some part of border in common, it cancels out to give a new relation. (See the picture: if $xy=1$ and $y^{-1}z=1$, then $xz=1$).

So, it remains to show that $a^7 b a b^7 a^{-7} b^{-1} a^{-1} b^{-7}=1$ does not follow from $a^2 b a^{-2} b^{-1}=1$  and $ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2} = 1$. Consider $S_3$ and let $a=(1 2), b= (13)$, then $a^2=1, b^2=1$, but $abab$ and $baba$ are different, since they are distinct 3-cycles.

These two methods (colorings and group theory) can be applied to any problem of the same sort (covering some cell figure with given figures).

The question is, **are there examples of problems for which one of the methods is more powerful than the other**, i.e. one method gives a solution while no solution using the other method is known?

For example, there is the following problem:

> A table $a\times b$ can be covered by rectangles of the form $n\times 1$ and $1 \times n$ only when $n|a$ or $n|b$.

But this problem can be solved by either of the two methods.

Comment: Why you generate $a^2ba^{-2}b^{-1}$? What it is for?

Comment: My first thought would be to look at problems on a Möbius strip. Or more generally, a non-orientable surface.